# How to correctly implement both example.com/username and example.com/id123?

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to let users to have customized urls, such as `example.com/username`, but I do not want to force them to do this, so in this case I would like to have addresses like this one: `example.com/id123`

Current approach:

```
# root urls.py
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^((?P<user_id>[i][d]\d+)|(?P<username>[\w.+-]+))/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_user')),

# profiles/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.profiles_home, name='profiles_home'),
]

# profiles/views.py
def profiles_home(request, user_id=None, username=None):
    if user_id:
        user_id = int(user_id.replace('id', ''))
        user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=user_id)
    else:
        user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, username=username)
    return render(request, 'profiles/profiles_home.html', {'profile_user': user})
```

This approach is not flexible. Particularly the problem is with navigation\menu, where I want to make a button `My page`. For navigation I use `django-sitetree`, where there is no built-in feature to use 'double'-link for 1 button which would depend on whether user has username or not. The scheme, which `sitetree` uses in order to connect buttons to links is defining `url_namespace:url_name`.

Could anyone advise me how to improve/simplify my URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a new field `url` to the `UserProfile` model:

```
url = models.CharField(_('URL address'), max_length=30, unique=True)
```

and the rest parts:

```
# main url
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # My url
    url(r'^(?P<user_url>[\w.-]+)/', include('profiles.urls', namespace='profiles_username')),
]

# profiles.urls (my app's urls)
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.profiles_home, name='profiles_home'),
]

# profiles.views
def profiles_home(request, user_url):
    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, url=user_url)

    return render(request, 'profiles/profiles_home.html', {'user_profile_form': user})
```

`url` generates once the user is created. Because I use `AllAuth`, I have `Adaptor` which looks like:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.account.utils import user_username, user_email, user_field

class UserProfileAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):

        data = form.cleaned_data
        first_name = data.get('first_name')
        last_name = data.get('last_name')
        email = data.get('email')
        username = data.get('username')
        user_email(user, email)
        user_username(user, username)

        if first_name:
            user_field(user, 'first_name', first_name)
        if last_name:
            user_field(user, 'last_name', last_name)
        if 'password1' in data:
            user.set_password(data["password1"])
        else:
            user.set_unusable_password()
        self.populate_username(request, user)
        if commit:
            user.save()

        # Add user's url to User's model
        user.url = 'id'+str(user.pk)
        user.save()
        return user
```

It is also necessary to implement validation for user profile page in order to forbid user to use custom urls such as `id123456`, i.e. `id`+`nums`, but it is not currently implemented.

Answer (score 0):

for handling navigation buttons I normally map id=0 to current user, so here would be your view

```
def profiles_home(request, user_id=None, username=None):
    if user_id == 0:
       user = request.user
    else if user_id:
        user_id = int(user_id.replace('id', ''))
        user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, pk=user_id)
    else:
        user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, username=username)
    return render(request, 'profiles/profiles_home.html', {'profile_user': user})
```